# Delphi: auto scroll for String Grid

Tags: string, delphi, grid, scroll

how to make an auto scroll for a String Grid?

A property "Row" or "TopRow" does not help if a String Grid is invisible (e.g. on a hidden frame): no cells are selected. If to show it - it's cell becomes selected and "Row"/"TopRow" works.

Try. In a design time. A String Grid: 100 rows, visible:=false. On a button's click:

```
StringGrid1.Row := 99; 
StringGrid1.Visible := true.
```

And return "visible" to true for the String Grid. Please see a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: just curious, why do need to autoscroll if its not visible?

Comment: switch a frame-->the frame and a String Grid on it-->visible-->a scroll is on the top. I need on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`HandleNeeded`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_HandleNeeded.html) before setting the `row` if the string grid has never shown before:

```
StringGrid1.HandleNeeded;
StringGrid1.Row := 99;

// later
StringGrid1.Visible := True;
```

Initially invisible, the string grid window has not been created yet. Setting the `row` sets the property but cannot scroll a non-existing window.

Comment: The handle for a WinControl is the window handle, to have the window handle the VCL has to create the window of the control.

Comment: Bug!!! Before "StringGrid1.Row := 99" I change columns' width. If to use "HandleNeeded" then Grid Lines have old positions and new ones at one time; text is showed incorrectly !!!

Comment: @maxfax - Couldn't duplicate with a simple test, sorry. StringGrid1.Invalidate helps?

Answer (score 0):

When i try the following code it seems to work the same in all three cases, visible, unvisiblae and unvisible parent:

```
  StringGrid1.TopRow := 5;
  showmessage(inttostr(StringGrid1.TopRow)); //shows 5
  StringGrid1.Visible := false;
  StringGrid1.TopRow := 2;
  showmessage(inttostr(StringGrid1.TopRow)); //shows 2
  StringGrid1.Parent.Visible := false;
  StringGrid1.TopRow := 1;
  showmessage(inttostr(StringGrid1.TopRow)); //shows 1
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Try. In a design time. A String Grid: 100 rows, visible:=false. On a button's click:  StringGrid1.Row := 99; StringGrid1.Visible := true. And then return "visible" to true for the String Grid. Please see difference.